# Codename One - Start editing in the search bar programmatically

Tags: codenameone

I need to start editing in the search bar programmatically when the Form is shown. Because I didn't find any API for that, I wrote this code inside the Form:

```
 addShowListener(l -> {
        for (int i = 0; i <= getToolbar().getComponentCount(); i++) {
            if (getToolbar().getComponentAt(i) instanceof Button) {
                Button btn = (Button) getToolbar().getComponentAt(i);
                if (btn.getUIID().equals("TitleCommand")) {
                    btn.pressed();
                    btn.released();
                }
                if (btn.getUIID().equals("BackCommand")) {

                    btn.addActionListener(ev -> {
                        backForm.showBack();
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

The problems of this code:

- it relies on the current implementation of the method `Form.getToolbar().addSearchCommand`, that created in the toolbar a button with UIID `TitleCommand` (the search icon on the right) and another button with UIID `BackButton` (the arrow on the left).
- my listener added to the back button doesn't work: instead of show the `backForm`, it shows the toolbar without the search bar.

So... my question is how to implement what I need with a better coding. Is it necessary to do an RFE to expose an API like `Toolbar.startSearchEditingAsync()`? And how can I change the default actionListener of backButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to initiate it before it's shown you might need something more elaborate similar to `Form.setEditOnShow()`.

This seemed a bit simpler in my head when I started it but once I started I had to finish so I implemented this here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/86fea99196dd5a453988ede8217e0809e529469a

It should work, let me know if it has issues.

Comment: Great work, thank you! I'm going to comment your commit to report a (small) issue about the back button.